# How to get with an applet data posted with php?

Tags: java, security, post, applet, passwords

I'm making a website with a registration form. I wrote my own program to "hash" the password in java and I want to embed my java applet in the registration form to hash it before I send it to my database. I can't just add it to the url after a question mark because it is unsafe to store passwords that way so I want to use the post method with php and somehow to read it with my applet.

I saw a few questions in here and read a few tutorials about getting data posted with php GET method. However, the information I want to pass to my applet has to be secured and I don't want it to be showed in the URL.

Is there any way for my applet to get data posted with the POST method? something like $_REQUEST but with an applet?

Answer (score 2):

This won't actually improve your security at all. Hashing the user's password before it is sent to the server makes the hash equivalent to a password, as an attacker that sniffs the hash from the network can reuse it to log in themselves. They won't know the original password, but it's no longer needed by anything besides the password hasher, which can be bypassed.

Use SSL to secure your site if password sniffing is a concern.

Comment: It would provide additional security if I'm using the applet to get some more information on the PC to be added to the password.

Comment: No, it would not. So long as that data is sent to the server, then it can be captured by an attacker and replayed. (And if it is not sent to the server, there is no way for the server to verify the results.)

Comment: It won't be useful against sniffing but it would be helpful against  my database being compromised. (just like any hashing), if i'll be using https it should provide some security against sniffing.

Comment: Performing password hashing within your application is already sufficient to defend against a database compromise. Once you've done that appropriately and enabled SSL, there is no need to add additional encryption (e.g, using Java) on the client side.

Comment: If I'm using a short password a compromised database would be a threat to security. If I'm adding to the password some personal data that I get on the client using java it would make my password bigger and safer.

Comment: That's only the case if you are using a weak password hash. Use something appropriately strong, like scrypt or PBKDF2, and that won't be a concern.